# Analog Devices Footprint issues: ADP7156

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, kicad, footprint

I have designed a circuit with a voltage regulator(ADP7156) from Analog Devices in KiCad. I have chosen the package type as 8-lead SOIC since I am planning to hand solder it to the PCB. While creating the footprint, I found the dimension of datasheet a little confusing. [image]

From the picture, I figured out basic footprint as follows(drew in paint for clarification purpose)
[image]

X=0.41mm,

Y=1.05mm (=(6-3.9)/2 mm), here 6 is median ,

C=4.95mm (=Y+3.9),

E=1.27mm

2.29mmX2.29mm for exposed pad

Am I good to go draw the footprint in KiCad Footprint editor with these information I collected from Data Sheet. I usually find the recommended pcb layout on other manufacturer's datasheet which helped a lot to draw the footprint easily. Please guide me.

Comment: You need to make the pads extend out beyond the leads by 0.5 to 1 mm on each side to leave room for a solder fillet.  Likewise they should be wider than the lead width, you currently have the pads 0.41 mm wide while the lead can be up to 0.51 mm. This would be difficult to solder well.

Comment: Do you mean Y=1.05+0.5=1.55mm, Rest of them are okay?@pericynthion

Comment: Increase all of C, Y and X.  Find a recommended SO-8 footprint from Analog or another manufacturer as reference.

Answer (score 1):

SOIC is SOIC, they're mostly all the same. You can adjust pad dimensions depending on how you want your solder fillet. Making pads a bit longer makes it easier to solder by hand.

When designing a PCB, I usually order the parts first, then print the PCB on a sheet of paper, and place any doubtful parts on the printout to check for errors. This is especially useful with connectors, and often avoids errors.

Comment: SOIC does come in different widths, so beware of that, but it will be obvious if you look at the dimensions. This one has the exposed pad to deal with too.